# Weird behavior in project.afterEvaluate when move from Gradle 7.5 to 8.0 version

Tags: java, gradle, plugins

We are trying to move from Gradle 7.5 to 8.0.
We are having problems with a plugin when we try to recover several extension properties.
In our build.gradle file, we have an extructure like:

```
Object1 {
    propertie1 "value1" 
    
    object2 {
        propertie2 "value2"
        propertie3 "value3"
        propertie4 "value4"
    }
}
```

In the plugin code, we are doing:

```
public void apply(Project project) {
    NamedDomainObjectContainer<DocumentResource> resources = project.container(DocumentResource.class);
    Object1 extension = project.getExtensions().create("Object1", Object1.class, project, resources);
    project.afterEvaluate(action -> {
        System.out.println(extension.getPropertie1());
        System.out.println(extension.getobject2());
```

With Gradle 7.5 the code works ok and both values are present, but with 8.0 version, second value is null; even more, if we modify the the order in build.gradle file, defining the object2 before propertie1, in 8.0 version both values are null.

Doing tests, we notice that if the object2 is moved out of the Object1, Gradle 8.0 works ok:

```
Object1 {
    propertie1 "value1" 
}
object2 {
    propertie2 "value2"
    propertie3 "value3"
    propertie4 "value4"
}
```

Any idea about how to solve it?

Object1 class looks like:

```
import org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer;
import org.gradle.api.Project;

import groovy.lang.Closure;

public class Object1 {
    NamedDomainObjectContainer<Object3> resources;
    private Project project;
    private String propertie1;
    private Object2 object2;
    
    public Object1(Project project, NamedDomainObjectContainer<Object3> resources) {
        this.project = project;
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }   
    
    void resources(Closure<?> closure) {
        resources.configure(closure);
    }
    
    public NamedDomainObjectContainer<DocumentResource> getResources() {
        return resources;
    }

    public void setResources(NamedDomainObjectContainer<DocumentResource> resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
    }
    
    void propertie1(String propertie1) {
        this.propertie1 = propertie1;
    }

    public String getpropertie1() {
        return propertie1;
    }

    void object2(Object2 object2) {
        this.object2 = object2;
    }
    
    public Object2 object2() {
        return object2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `Object1` Gradle extension class look like?

Comment: Hi @Edric I added how Object1 looks like